# A browser tool that looks up translations and saves them for later to recap

Tags: browser-addons, translation

English it not my native language, but quite often I'll read English articles from various sources and stumble upon technical terms that I can have translated on the go using the [Google dictionary](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja) extension for chrome.

While this is straight forward and fast, I tend to forget the terms if I read their translations only once. I'd like to be able to view all the translations that I have looked up so that I can read and study them again later.

Are you aware of such a browser extension or another tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of fairly recently, the Google Dictionary Chrome extension supports this functionality. Simply visit the options page (accessible from Menu > Tools > Extensions or from the dictionary toolbar button) and enable the "word history" feature.

Comment: Oh yeah! I kindly asked for this feature in a bug report. Awesome!